# CodeIgniter Query Builder Class failed to achieve multiple where result as normal SQL query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**Problem**:-

How to add () between multiple where if you want to execute first 2 where first then last one. as you can add bracket in sql mention below.

**Ci Query**

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('patient_details');

$this->db->where('pt_id', $login_user_id);
$this->db->or_where_in('sub_pt_id', $implode_child_array);
$this->db->where('status', 'Complete');

$query = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

**Sql**

```
    **SELECT COUNT(*)
 AS `numrows`
FROM `patient_details`
WHERE `pt_id` = '79'
OR `sub_pt_id` IN('80')
AND `status` = 'Complete'**
```

**What i want is like below**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM `patient_details`
WHERE (`pt_id` = '79'
OR `sub_pt_id` IN('80'))
AND `status` = 'Complete'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
[Query grouping](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping)

```
$this->db->group_start()
$this->db->where('pt_id', $login_user_id);
$this->db->or_where_in('sub_pt_id', $implode_child_array);
$this->db->group_end()
$this->db->where('status', 'Complete');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group_start()` and `group_end()` functions. They work like **open bracket** and **close bracket** : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Your code will look like this :

```php
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('patient_details');

$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->where('pt_id', $login_user_id);
$this->db->or_where_in('sub_pt_id', $implode_child_array);
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->where('status', 'Complete');

$query = $this->db->count_all_results();
```